# Условное придаточное или обстоятельство условия?

Tags: синтаксис

**Лицо его казалось бы совсем молодым, если бы не грубые ефрейторские складки, пересекавшие щёки и шею** (И. Ильф и Е. Петров).

Если это сложноподчинённое предложение с придаточным условным, что где ГО придаточного? Может, здесь простое предложение (=при условии отсутствия на нем ...складок...)?  Но может ли обстоятельство условия присоединяться подчинительным союзом?

Answer (score 2):

Ваши сомнения верны, условный союз присоединяет придаточное условное.Придаточное можно отнести к неполному с пропуском сказуемого присутствовали (если бы не присутствовали грубые...), эллиптическое.Кое-кто из учёных характеризует такие предложения как односоставные назывные, отрицательные. В любом случае подлежащее складки, сказуемое отсутствует.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила! Правильно ли я понимаю, что единственный случай присоединения второстепенного члена предложения подчинительным союзом - это сравнительный оборот?

Comment: Вероятно, да - сравнивать можно как предметы, так и целые процессы. Иногда называют простыми предложениями сложноподчинённые с придаточным, состоящим из одного союзного слова: Он не придёт. И я знаю почему.Знаю что?-почему. Это придаточное в роли дополнения.

Comment: Есть большая по объему тема, связанная с устойчивыми оборотами на основе подчинительных союзов, но они не обособляются: Выбирай что хочешь. Поступай как угодно. Будь счастлив с кем хочешь. 
 Живите как знаете. Также подчинительный союз ХОТЯ может использоваться как сочинительный: "Это был прекрасный, хотя и несколько печальный город".